# Expand Image Vertically Without Disrupting the Flow with Javascript & CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, positioning

> My Progress is @ http://codebucket.webatu.com/code/portfoliotest/index.html
>
> Code on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/warmlaundry/qJbG4/70/

I want to make the edges of the 'f' and 'l' stretch to the edge of the page.  I'm just expanding the height of two images that sandwich the word.

I want the word itself to stay put, and I don't want the expanding images to displace any other elements.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I imagine it has to do with positioning correctly, but I still don't have a full grasp of the subtleties of CSS positioning.

I apologize if this question is a repost; I couldn't think of a good way to phrase the question without posting my own example.

---

edit: here's my code (since the link seems to be bad)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#portfolioBottom{position:relative;top:-1px;}
#portfoliotop{position:relative;top:1px;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

var heightBottom;
var heightTop;
var interval;

function addHeight(){
    document.getElementById("portfolioBottom").style.width="249px";
    heightBottom = parseInt(document.getElementById("portfolioBottom").style.height);
    heightBottom=heightBottom + 5;
    document.getElementById("portfolioBottom").style.height=heightBottom;
    
    document.getElementById("portfolioTop").style.width="210px";
    heightTop = parseInt(document.getElementById("portfolioTop").style.height);
    heightTop=heightTop + 5;
    document.getElementById("portfolioTop").style.height=heightTop; 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="interval=self.setInterval('addHeight()',1);">Start</button><button onclick="interval=window.clearInterval(interval)">Stop</button><br /><br />

<img src="http://codebucket.webatu.com/code/portfoliotest/portfolio top.png" id="portfolioTop" style="height:6px;" /><br />
<img src="http://codebucket.webatu.com/code/portfoliotest/portfolio.jpg" id="portfolio" /><br />
<img src="http://codebucket.webatu.com/code/portfoliotest/portfolio bottom.png" id="portfolioBottom" style="height:6px;" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want it stretched only to the maximum height? and the text to be vertically centered before and after the "animation" ?

Comment: what exactly are the 'f' and 'l' you are referring to? It's hardly clear from the example you've given.

Comment: He means the F and L in portFoLio... It was rather clear.

Comment: Yeah, that probably would be clear if not for the fact I'm getting redirected to http://www.000webhost.com/admin-review

Comment: Eh, that admin-review page doesn't have the elements you're referring to right? Can you put an example up on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Khez - Yes I want it to stretch to the maximum height, and for the text to stay exactly where it is positioned (I think that's what you mean by vertically centered)

@Chris & waitinforatrain - Sorry the link was bad. I tried to get my code working on jsfiddle (very cool service btw!) but had some trouble, so I've just posted it with live links to the images.  Hopefully that will work.

Comment: scratch that, here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/warmlaundry/qJbG4/70/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone with positioning the two extended bits and also I put the images as a background image to divs which then did the work.

Have just used your images (with positioning it could probably be done with a single image doing both bits, and sorry I didn't correct the missing pixel off the main image, I just overlapped the pixel for now, hence the cutoff look  corrected the missing pixel on the main image would fix that ;) -

then, once positioned - I just animated the height and top/bottom negative positions simultaneously

I can't do JS so the demo's with jQuery, but hopefully the logic of the positioning will help you do the same in JS

also in mine I restricted the body height to stop it scrolling on forever, this might not be practical in real terms, but becasue the two images always go to the same height, the reverse effect brought them back together too.. so advantages maybe?

#### [the live example](http://jsbin.com/oriyu4/2)

Comment: thanks so much for the response, Claire--very helpful! And sorry for the delay, haven't been on SO for a while!

Answer (score 1):

What about just using CSS and positioning it as a background image?

```
html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background:#fff url("//imgur.com/qJMrs.png") 2em 50% fixed no-repeat;
}
```

### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/SMs9j](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/SMs9j/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/SMs9j/show/))

Comment: Thanks Marcel, that's helpful but I was looking to animate the two stretched bits of the image.